# Keeping photos between Lion and iOS synchronised

Tags: macos, ios, photos.app

I own iPhoto on both platforms. Is it possible to keep the photos synchronised between the phone and mac?

I don't mean simply transferring them from phone to mac when WIFI is available. I want when I delete a photo from the computer to have it deleted on the phone automatically. Or alternatively when photos are synched from phone to mac, they should get deleted on phone.

Is either of the above possible with iPhoto? I can't find an option for it at any obvious place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, no. Pretty much the only thing the two apps share is a name right now. They're quite independent of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use iCloud for this?

Comment: It should work to use iCloud and photo stream if you only care about 30 days / 1000 photos. In general, iCloud document sync is for key/value stores - not storing major volumes of data online.